# Is there an Apache equivalent of nginx mod_zip?

Tags: php, apache, nginx, web

I have been working a web app where I need to allow the user to select a number of files and allow them to download said files as a zip file. I am working with lots of data so storing the zip file in memory or on disk isn't an option.

I am currently using Apache and haven't been able to find any solutions to be able to dynamically create and stream zip files to a client. One thing I did find was nginx `mod_zip` that seems to do exactly what I want.

What would be an Apache equivalent to `mod_zip`, or another solution to dynamically zip and stream zip files (without using disk space or loading the whole file in memory)?